# can we implement the Airwatch single sign on for hybrid apps

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, single-sign-on

I have two ionic + angular app installed in my device.
I wanted to implement  the single sign on with Airwatch
is it possible to implement the Airwatch single sign on for hybrid applications